# Best place for collaboratively developed, courseware

Tags: collaboration

What sites can I use to access free repositories of collaboratively edited text-books, curriculum, class notes and courseware?

Some good ones that I'm aware of:

**[WikiEducator](http://wikieducator.org/Main_Page)**

**[OER Commons](http://www.oercommons.org/)**

**[Connexions](http://cnx.org/)**

Comment: [MIT OpenCourseware](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) is one.

Comment: [www.videolectures.net](http://videolectures.net) is one of my favourites

Comment: This list of X needs to be a CW as there is no single answer.

Comment: [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) has a lot of awesome video lectures.

Comment: There's a disconnect between the title and the question.  You're not just after free e-learning, you're after collaboratively prepared material.  e.g. iTunes U is free e-learning, but is not collaboratively edited material.

Comment: @Tony: Good point

Comment: **[iTunes U](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/whats-on.html)**

Comment: the answers should go in an actual answer. If you want to make a compiled list of answers, we can do that; but they should be separate from the question.

Comment: This isn't exactly the type of questions well suited for this system, but at the very least, questions that ask users to create a list of answers should be made community wiki. I converted this question for you.

Comment: questions like this one probably should be on the [proposed] [Open and Free Content](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29415/open-and-free-content?referrer=fQo9p04jLPIbaDTh4NmFiQ2) proposal on Area51 :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually stick to Wikipedia and occasionally [WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Main_Page) for most of my general reading. From there, I'll usually jump around to the different sources cited for more in-depth material.

For professional topics, I turn to the IEEE and ACM, since I'm a member and have access to their libraries and e-courses. Depending on your field of expertise, I would recommend joining a professional society if one exists - their digital libraries alone are usually well worth the cost of membership and the content is professionally produced by the leaders in the field. These aren't usually collaboratively edited, but they are sometimes textbooks, white papers, and course material (depending on the specific organization).